# Nginx Config to serve .json without CORS restriction with ddev

Tags: nginx, ddev, cors

I have Craft 4 installed and use it locally with ddev.
Ddev uses nginx in my case and I want to enable serving .json files from a subdirectory within `/web`.

What do I have to add to the nginx.conf file?

I tried:

```
# json
location ~* \.(?:json?)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
}

location /data/data-charging-stations/ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept';
    expires    7d;
    access_log off;
}
```

(Whereas my json is within `/web/data/data-charging-stations`).

my ddev config yaml is defined to use `webserver_type: nginx-fpm`

And I found an nginx config here:

`/.nginx-config/nginx.conf`

I don't know if that config is even active. using `curl` to test the json never shows the added headers.

I would be very glad if somebody could help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

*I know this is an oldish question, but I hit a similar issue, so leaving this here for posterity...*

Per the [ddev docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#custom-nginx-configuration) you can edit the nginx conf file at `.ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf`.

First of all, you need to remove the `#ddev-generated` comment line near the top so that ddev doesn't overwrite your changes, and you will probably also want to `git add -f .ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf` once you've customised it so that you can share your changes with others / persist them over time.

You can then edit the nginx config, run `ddev exec nginx -t` to test your config is valid and if so finally run `ddev restart` to see your changes. For your specific use-case, just drop your `location {}` blocks inside the `server {}` block in `.ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf` and  `ddev restart`.

Comment: Oh thanks. That's great. I will try the next time I run into this issue. I know, that I was not able to solve it, when I asked this question...

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for the clear instructions